# How to turn a generic ASP.net 4.5 MVC 5 login/register into a front facing modal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a simple CRUD application connected to a SQL back end and want to use the generic login/register views but want them to appear as a modal - so to be specific as soon as you type in the website name and press return the first thing you see is the login/register modal in the center of the screen preventing anyone access who does not have a login? I am new to Web development and require help with this.

I am using entity framework and database first migration.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your research effort?

Comment: I have looked at this youtube https://youtu.be/ZJXbom3hMNY and some website articles but nothing specific to entity framework I can find? I want to use exisiting generic set up but modify it into a modal? Was hoping their was specific help on this.

Comment: A quick search resulted in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454074/asp-net-mvc-login-modal-dialog-lightbox and this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293765/asp-net-mvc-login-modal-problems-redirect-goes-to-modal Does that give you a start?

Comment: Yes that helps a lot thanks. also, putting my ego aside simply using the [Authorize] attribute in my class achieved this - simple and effective use of identity framework.

Comment: namespace YerraUserManager.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AspNetUsersController : Controller
    {
        private UserManagerDB db = new UserManagerDB();

        // GET: AspNetUsers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.AspNetUsers.ToList());
        }